# Use XPath in JMeter to get attribute value

Tags: xpath, jmeter, extractor

Below is a sample response from JMeter tool.

```
<input name="requestId" type="hidden" value="-1859748216"/>
```

I try the following XPath `//input[@name='requestId']`, but it doesn't work, I would like to take only the numeric value -1859748216

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value attribute using `/@value`

```
//input[@name='requestId']/@value
```

Prefer using newer/improved [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) over XPath Extractor

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use XPath, you need something like `//input[@name='requestId']/@value`

[image]

However XPath Extractor is quite resource intensive as it keeps entire DOM in memory, when it comes to getting the values from HTML content I would rather recommend going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) leaving XPath for XML or when CSS Selectors are not powerful enough

Example setup:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)